# blueimp jQuery File Upload in a div

Tags: jquery, html, file, upload, blueimp

I have been trying to integrate the blueimp jquery file uploader into my site and although things are pretty much working there is still one problem.  The file upload is triggered when I drop a file into any part of the browser screen but in this particular case I only want it to happen when I drop the files into a div.

My code so far is this:

```
 <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>jQuery File Upload Example</title>
</head>
<body>
<style>
.bar {
    height: 18px;
    background: green;
}
</style>
<div id="progress">
    <div class="bar" style="width: 0%;"></div>
</div>
<form class="fileupload" action="upload.asp">
<div style="position:relative;border:1px solid black;height:200px;">
<h1>Drag file(s) into here or click Choose Files
</div>
<input id="fileupload" type="file" name="file1" data-url="upload.asp" multiple>
</form>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/vendor/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.iframe-transport.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.fileupload.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).bind('drop dragover', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});

$('#fileupload').fileupload({
    /* ... */
    progressall: function (e, data) {
        var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
        $('#progress .bar').css(
            'width',
            progress + '%'

        );
        if (progress==100) {
        alert('All done');
        $('#progress .bar').css( 'width', '0%' );
        }
    }
});
</script>
</body> 
</html>
```

I have tried to make follow the instructions on this page:

https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Multiple-File-Upload-Widgets-on-the-same-page

It talks about making change to the main.js file but because I am using the basic version I don't use this file (I think).

Hope someone can help!

Thanks very much

Ed

Answer (score 0):

You should set

```
dropZone: $(this)
```

in the options. This also makes sure that if you have multiple `<div>`s that accept uploads you don't get multiple uploads.

My current code looks like this:

```
$('.dragTarget').each(function() {
    $(this).fileupload({
        ...
        dropZone:  $(this), 
        ...
};
```